# Memory Pool Allocation

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, operating-system

I am currently working on implementing my own Memory Pool for an Operating Systems course and am wondering if there are any ways that I can search for available memory on my system.

I'd like to first program this in C/C++ and then transfer it over to our language of choice for the course which is BCPL.

My intention is to probe my available Heap Memory to figure out how much memory I can safely use and mess with. Is there an easy of doing this, or would it be more efficient to just declare a static size, say, 10,000 bytes?

Thanks

Comment: ***My intention is to probe my available Heap Memory to figure out how much memory I can safely use*** Whatever OS you are using should have some OS specific function for that.

Comment: So, being on Windows, would it be a function that could be a part of the Win32 API?

Comment: Just want to point out that 10KB is trivial for almost any system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention you are on Windows, it sounds like the function you want is [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx). Specifically, from the documentation:

> You can use the GlobalMemoryStatusEx function to determine how much memory your application can allocate without severely impacting other applications.

After that you can just call malloc/HeapAlloc/VirtualAlloc to get a large block of contiguous memory to play with.

If by "implementing a memory pool", you mean you want to implement an allocator, then most implementations of `malloc()` would call `VirtualAlloc()` to map more memory into the process as needed, so you might want to play with that. If you wanted to implement an operating system, then the next step would be re-implementing `VirtualAlloc()` which would actually involve implementing a virtual memory management system.